# 'let' in record telescope

Tags: record, let, agda

Is something like a `let` or `where` clause allowed inside an Agda record telescope in order to introduce a definition local to the telescope?

[This discussion](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2012/004501.html) suggests the following should be legal:

```
record _×_ (let ⋆ = Set) (A B : ⋆) : Set where
   constructor _,_
   field
      fst : A
      snd : B
```

[This change request](https://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?can=2&q=710&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=710) describes a slightly different syntax:

```
record _×_ (let ⋆ = Set in (A B : ⋆)) : Set where
   constructor _,_
   field
      fst : A
      snd : B
```

(The issue is marked as Accepted and there seems to be a patch but I don't know if it's been incorporated officially.)

However Agda 2.4.0.2 doesn't accept either of these.

After the colon I seem to be able to use `let` as I would expect:

```
record _×_ (A B : Set) : let ⋆ = Set in ⋆ where
   constructor _,_
   field
      fst : A
      snd : B
```

Is there some reason I can use a `let` in the telescope part of the record declaration (when giving its indices), but not when giving its parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the release notes for 2.4.0:

- Telescoping lets: Local bindings are now accepted in telescopes
  of **modules**, **function types**, and **lambda-abstractions**.

So no, the patch you mentioned hasn't been incorporated (yet).

The reason you can use `let` in the last code snippet is that you are using it in an expression. In other words, the index part of the declaration is not a telescope.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That could be a pain for what I'm currently doing, unless I can find another way of formulating things. (Maybe I can use a module to do some of it.) Thanks for clarifying the meaning of "telescope", too.

Comment: You could define the type inside a module and move the parameters to the module telescope. I'm not aware of any major differences between these two. Also, I don't think I clarified the meaning of telescope that much, let me remedy it: a telescope is only the `(a1 a2 ... an : T1) ... (b1 b2 ... bn : T2)` part.

Comment: Thanks again. I've accepted your answer, but included a module-based solution as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to emulate `let` using a local module:

```
private
   module Dummy (let ⋆ = Set) where
      record _×_  (A B : ⋆) : Set where
         constructor _,_
         field
            fst : A
            snd : B
open Dummy
```

Better still, by using an anonymous module, the `open Dummy` can be omitted:

```
module _ (let ⋆ = Set) where
   record _×_  (A B : ⋆) : Set where
      constructor _,_
      field
         fst : A
         snd : B
```

(As explained in the [Agda 2.3.2 release notes](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Version-2-3-2), the latter is essentially equivalent to the former.)

Comment: If you want to use `_×_` from other global modules (i.e. from another file), you should open the module publicly: `open Dummy public`. As far as I know this (sadly) cannot be done for anonymous modules.